# What's causing this thin line between two divs on ipad?

Tags: css, ipad

Viewable only on an actual iPad/iPhone (and not on any virtual versions) I'm getting a thin, almost imperceptible line between the two bottom divs on [this website](http://www.strategies-coaching.com)

Strangely, the line disappears once you zoom in, and using borders or negative margins just makes the problem worse.(Don't judge my code, I had to jump through a lot of hoops because of the CMS-based hosting that the client vehemently did not want to move away from).

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the line as it looks on the iPad. You'll have click to zoom in to see it, as it's really thin.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1aUg.jpg]

And the offending section:

```
<div id="bottom_gradient">
    &nbsp; <br />
    <br />
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer_container">
        <div class="content_left_footer">
        <br />          
            <img src="images/slogan_icon.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
            <b>t.</b> 787.439.0924<br />
            <b>fax</b> 1.888.201.1222<br />
            <b>e-mail:</b> econcepcion@strategies-coaching.com<br />
            P.O. BOX 934 Dorado, P.R. 00646
            <br />
            <br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_right_footer">
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
            <div class="member">
            <br />
            MIEMBRO DE<br />
            <br />
            MEMBER OF
            <br />
            <br />
            </div>
        <div class="images">
        <div class="shrm"></div>
        <div class="icp"></div>
        <div class="astd"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div></div>
<!-- the line appears above this div -->
<div class="column_center" style="color:white;text-align:center;">
   copyright 2012 Strategies
   <br />
   <br />
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the edits, I made your image from a link to a image with a clickable link. you can delete non relevant old comments by pressing the `X` at the end of the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `<div id="white">` background might be peeking through after the `<div id="footer">`.  Try moving the `<div id="footer">` outside and after the `<div id="white">` and see if that helps.

Or if you can't do that (or it doesn't work), try setting the height of the `<div id="footer">` to more than is needed and set it's margin such that it will extend below the `<div id="white">`, thereby covering the little bit that is peeking through.

Comment: Both of these solutions worked, though I had to take the height and margin to slightly ridiculous levels to make that solution work (height went from 230px to 395px, with a margin of -200px). The second one is better for me, since with the CMS hosting I have to upload files individually, so any solution that is CSS-only is best. Again, thanks!